# Autodesk Forge host dependencies on a local server

Tags: angular, typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have an angular/ typescript implementation of the forge viewer which is currently loading a couple of dependencies from the Autodesk server. But to guarantee to our customers that these files are always online, I would like to host these files on one of our company’s servers. I downloaded a package from the Autodesk Forge Extractor tool and tried to host this on a local server, but unfortunately this seems to function on version `2.10` rather than `2.13` which is breaking some of our functionality.

In addition to that, it looks like every extracted package comes with the models and textures included, but since we load our models from our company’s server we would like to host a package that only contains the files listed below. We aren’t able to use the Autodesk extract tool for all our models to create packages.

Is there a way to reliably host the below dependencies without having to store the whole model or without having to make references to the exact model?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/style.css" />
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/three.min.js?v=2.13.*"></script>
<script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js?v=2.13.*"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The forge Viewer is up to Version 3.1.1 I will suggest to use the latest version, quite a lot of things have changed since Version 2.13 and more from 2.10.

Make sure you always check the Changelogs in the Viewer Developer page
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/overview/changelog/

Check the following posts so you can learn what changed.

- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v215
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v216
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v217
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v311

Another way I can think of, would be to copy the entire JS and also the css files to your server hosted local files, that will reference from your project.

Go to these links, copy the entire source and name it something meaningful and related to the API so you know in the future what are they.

CSS

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/style.css?v=2.13

JS

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/three.js?v=2.13 
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=2.13

You can always get the minified js if you add "min" before the .js 
Keep in mind, these will not get updated, you will have to do the manual work when you decide to make the update.

Comment: Hi Jaime, we waited with upgrading our viewer because of a couple of event listeners that would break in newer versions. I already reported this issue to the Autodesk helpdesk with ticketnumber `#1520`, but regardless, I don't see any changes in later versions of the viewer that would help me in my problem. I am looking for a way to host the viewer source files on one of our own servers seperatly from our models. Is this possible in any way?

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if that helps. Cheers

Comment: If you want to self-host the viewer API, it's doable, however there are many more files than the 3 which are mentioned here (other files are being loaded on demand internally by the viewer as needed). You will need to grab all of them. For licensing reason, we are not allowed to provide a direct download link for the complete API. Just PM me - philippe.leefsma 'at' autodesk.com - your email address and I will send you v 3.1.1 directly.